# Passing parameters to TThread::Queue using lambda in C++ Builder

Tags: lambda, c++builder, tthread

I want to do something like this:

```cpp
void TForm2::SetMsg(UnicodeString fMsg)
{
// If thread is not main Queue...
if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
    TThread::Queue( nullptr, [&]() -> void { Form2->SetMsg(fMsg); } );
    return;
    }

// If thread is main then print directly...
Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg);
}
```

So I simply call `SetMsg("mymessage");` and regardless in which thread it is called from it prints properly. The above would work except the `UnicodeString` gets deallocated before lambda is called.

It is my understanding that the lambda above should remain allocated in this form, and it indeed works if I hardcode the string in the lambda itself instead of fMsg parameter. So how do I pass the parameter then?

I could allocate it with new and delete later, but that fails for some reason too.

I tried:

```cpp
void TForm2::SetMsg(UnicodeString fMsg)
{
// If thread is not main Queue...
if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
    UnicodeString* p = new UnicodeString(fMsg);
    TThread::Queue( nullptr, [&]() -> void { try { Form2->SetMsg(*p); } __finally { delete p; } }  );
    return;
    }

// If thread is main then print directly...
Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg);
}
```

Would it be faster (less expensive) or easier with the `TThread::CreateAnonymousThread` ?

The first version works fine if `TThread::Synchronize` is used but I want to avoid thread blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above would work except the `UnicodeString` gets deallocated before lambda is called.

Your lambda is capturing the `UnicodeString` *by reference*, so when `SetMsg()` exits, the `UnicodeString` will be destroyed, leaving the reference inside the lambda dangling. The lambda needs to capture the `UnicodeString` *by value* instead to make its own *copy*.

Also, I would not recommend using the global `Form2` variable to call `SetMsg()` on, I would have the lambda capture `SetMsg`'s `this` pointer instead.

Try this:

```cpp
void TForm2::SetMsg(UnicodeString fMsg)
{
    // If thread is not main Queue...
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
        TThread::Queue( nullptr, [this, fMsg]{ this->SetMsg(fMsg); } );
        return;
    }

    // If thread is main then print directly...
    Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg);
}
```

Alternatively, don't have the lambda call `SetMsg()` a second time, just access the `Memo` directly instead, since you know the `GetCurrentThreadId()` check will be redundant at that point:

```cpp
void TForm2::SetMsg(UnicodeString fMsg)
{
    // If thread is not main Queue...
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
        TThread::Queue( nullptr, [this, fMsg]{ this->Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg); } );
        return;
    }

    // If thread is main then print directly...
    Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg);
}
```

> I could allocate it with `new` and `delete` later, but that fails for some reason too.

Your lambda is capturing the pointer *by reference*, so you are leaving the reference inside the lambda dangling when `SetMsg()` exits.  You need to capture the pointer *by value* instead:

```cpp
void TForm2::SetMsg(UnicodeString fMsg)
{
    // If thread is not main Queue...
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
        UnicodeString* p = new UnicodeString(fMsg);
        TThread::Queue( nullptr, [this, p]{ try { this->SetMsg(*p); /* or: this->Memo1->Lines->Add(*p); */ } __finally { delete p; } } );
        return;
    }

    // If thread is main then print directly...
    Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg);
}
```

In general, using a dynamic `UnicodeString` will work, though I would strongly suggest capturing a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead to handle the deallocation for you, instead of using a manual `try/__finally` block:

```cpp
void TForm2::SetMsg(UnicodeString fMsg)
{
    // If thread is not main Queue...
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
        // using unique_ptr, must be moved into the lambda
        auto p = std::make_unique<UnicodeString>(fMsg);
        TThread::Queue( nullptr, [this, p = move(p)]{ this->SetMsg(*p); /* or: this->Memo1->Lines->Add(*p); */ } );

        // using shared_ptr, can be copied by value
        auto p = std::make_shared<UnicodeString>(fMsg);
        TThread::Queue( nullptr, [this, p]{ this->SetMsg(*p); /* or: this->Memo1->Lines->Add(*p); */ } );

        return;
    }

    // If thread is main then print directly...
    Memo1->Lines->Add(fMsg);
}
```

> Would it be faster (less expensive) or easier with the `TThread::CreateAnonymousThread`?

No.  You are already running in a thread when calling `Queue()`, there is no reason to waste overhead spawning another thread.  And you would still have to deal with copying values into that thread's lambda/callback function.

Comment: Of course I knew that (capturing by reference vs copy) I just do references by "default" without thinking and almost never by copy which obviously is the key here. Thanks for the excellent and valuable answer!